# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 database engine will not install

Tags: microsoft-access, c#

I recently made an application to interact with an Access database file (.mdb). I have been using the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider for my development machine. When I try to install the program on the target computer (Windows 7), it keeps giving an error that says The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

This seems to be a common error that is caused, obviously, by the database provider not being installed. Through some research, I found that there is a 32-bit version from the Access 2007 Runtime, and 32-bit/64-bit versions available from newer versions of the runtime/database engine.

I initially tried the Access 2007 runtime to install the provider, as I am not sure that any computer running this application would be using 32-bit or 64-bit MS Office and wanted to avoid the compatibility check. While the installation was successful, the exception was still being thrown. I instead used the Access 2010 runtime just to see if it would work and still nothing.The drivers will not show up on the target machine.

After each installation above, I had opened up Powershell and ran

```
(New-Object system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator).GetElements()
```

which returned

```
SQLOLEDB
MSDataShape
ADsDSOObject
Windows Search Data Source
MSDASQL
MSDASQL Enumerator
SQLOLEDB Enumerator
MSDAOSP
MSIDXS
```

none of which are the ACE 12.0 provider. Just for comparisons sake, I ran this same command on my development machine which returned

```
SQLOLEDB
MSDataShape
SQLNCLI11
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0
ADsDSOObject
SQLNCLI11 Enumerator
Windows Search Data Source
MSDASQL
MSDASQL Enumerator
MSOLAP
MSOLAP
SQLOLEDB Enumerator
MSDAOSP
```

I even checked the ODBC Data Source Administrator (C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe) which shows no Access drivers on the target machine but shows that the ACEODBC.dll file is on my development machine.

I do not know what else to try. Every search I have done has said to either use the 2007 runtime or the 2010 engine, but neither are installing the driver on the machine. How else could I get the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider on my target machine(s)?

EDIT: It is also worth mentioning, as I had seen it in some other posts about the topic, that it is supposedly looking for ACEOLEDB.DLL in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14, however, there is no OFFICE14 folder on my target computer.

Comment: You might be running 64-bit Windows and there are no 64-bit Access drivers. Is your build configuration set to `x86` in the project's Properties, Build, Platform target?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, the build is targeting the x86 platform.

Comment: This might still be a mix-up of 32/64-bit products. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine) dedicated to this problem, and try out the various solutions. It might be better to uninstall all products, then reinstall the right ones.

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` would be a 64-bit version of `ODBC Data Source Administrator`.  64-bit support does not exist for `ACEOLEDB.DLL`.  **While I understand you are targetting to 32-bit I feel this information is important enough to point out.**  "there is no OFFICE14 folder on my target computer." - So what version of Office is installed?

Comment: @harrymc I have already gone through that post and tried the solutions in there to no avail. I have tried uninstalling my application as well as the Access runtimes and re-installing.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I thought I had mentioned that, it is Office 2013 32-bit.